# MySQL Update Null Values of a Table at Runtime

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, triggers, dynamic-sql

I am trying to update a table with `null` values. Here's the scenario:

In my **initial run**, the table would look like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item     | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | abc      | 10    | 20    | 30    |
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

However, in my **subsequent runs**, the table columns will have additional columns that would look like this:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | item     | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | abc      | 10    | 20    | 30    | null  | null  |
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2  | ghq      | null  | 40    | null  | 50    | 60    | -- triggers the update of row_1. At the same time should update row_2
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3  | xyz      | 70    | 80    | null  | 90    | null  | -- updates row_3 and same updates moving forward
+----+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Here's how it works in the backend:

1. The initial run creates the table.
2. In the subsequent runs, it alters the table to add the additional columns (col_4 & col_5).
3. Then, updates the records leaving some null cells.

Now, I want to fill the null cells with data coming from another table.

I am thinking on using the triggers but as you can see above, the nulls to be updated are triggered by the succeeding row. On the other hand, I am not really sure if stored procedures and functions will do.

I am a quick learner and I just need some clues or guides, at least, on what's the best approach to do this?

**ATTEMPT 1:** WHILE LOOP STORED PROCEDURE

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '@col_name' in 'field list'

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `fill_null_values`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0;          -- number of columns
    DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 0;          -- number of rows
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;          -- rows counter
    DECLARE e INT DEFAULT 0;          -- columns counter
    DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(100);    -- bad table column name
    
    /* initialize c = number of columns */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bad_table'
        INTO c;
    
    /* initialize r = number of rows */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_table INTO r;
    
    SET i = 0;
    SET e = 7; -- starts at column 7
    SET col_name = ''; 
    
    WHILE i <= r DO                                   
        WHILE e <= c DO

            /* get col_name */
            SET col_name = CONCAT("SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                                   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test_db' 
                                      AND TABLE_NAME = 'canvass_prices'
                                      AND ORDINAL_POSITION = e"); 
               
            /* update null values */
            SET @sql = CONCAT("UPDATE bad_table 
                               SET `",col_name,"` = (
                                   SELECT ref_data FROM ref_table 
                                   JOIN bad_table ON ref_table.id = bad_table.id 
                                   WHERE bad_table.ref_data = i) 
                               WHERE `",col_name,"` IS NULL");

            PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

            SET e = e + 1;
        END WHILE;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;    
END
```

Comment: This screams Bad DB Design. If you are likely to get new columns required, then make the database record the columns "down the page" so to speak `id | Item | ColName | ColValue |` for example. Then you can invent 1000 new `col_n` and never need to mess with the database structure

Comment: *triggers the update of row_1. At the same time should update row_2* Forget - this is impossible. Trigger can alter only the values in the row which' update causes its firing, and cannot affect on any other rows of the same table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's actually the requirement and I got no option. I did already your suggestion and pivot it to form a column, all at runtime. I just reached this point trying this time to fill the null cells.

Comment: @Akina Thank you and I can avoid already the trigger. I think the only option I have left is looping. What do you think?

Comment: I added my first attempt as an update to my question but I am getting an error on the variable `col_name`. I feel like I am almost getting it.

Comment: @Akina I have checked the loop and its fine. The error is confined only in update statement at `SET @col_name` design syntax error while it does not give an error on `WHERE @col_name`.

Comment: @RickyBelmont 1) As I see you make a common mistake - you think that declared `DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(100);` variable and user-defined `@col_name` variable is the same. I must tell you this is not true. 2) Another mistake - you use `UPDATE bad_table SET @col_name = ...`, the `INSERT` syntax claims that the column name must be at the place where user-defined variable name `@col_name` is typed. This result in error. If you hope that the variable will be replaced with its value - this is not true again. You need in prepared statement.

Comment: @Akina I have corrected the col_name above. Thanks for that. I was confused while keep on trying trying. Regarding PREPARED STATEMENT, I will try the `update null values` as prepared statement. I will get back to you.

Comment: @Akina I have updated my attempt 1 with prepare statement as you suggested. And I also tested with actual data instead of col_name and it's working. The error this time is isolated in where clause `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'col_name' in 'where clause'`. Almost right there!

Comment: Done! col_name issue need to change `",col_name,"` in prepare statement.